# react imports not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import a style variable from another file but it tells me that it's undefined

My directory:

```
  Components
    Login
        LoginForm.js
    appstyle.js
```

appstyle.js

```
export default AppStyles = {
    colour: {
        custom: 'rgb(86,200,95)'
    }
}
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppStyles from '../appstyle';
class LoginForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const header = {
            color: AppStyles.color.custom 
        }
    return (<div ><p style={header}> test </p></div>)


}
```

error:

```
./src/components/appstyle.js
  Line 1:  'AppStyles' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

What is wrong? I honestly cant see what i did that's making it not recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your export statement is wrong, if you want to name something you need to [declare a variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

Or you can also **NOT** name it, as it is a `default` export, and name the import only in your `Login` file.

```
export default { 
    [...]
}
```

Comment: your first suggestion gave me syntax error but your second suggestion worked. Thanks...

Comment: Yes, I corrected, sorry. You cannot export something as default AND declare a variable in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default AppStyles = {
    colour: {
        custom: 'rgb(86,200,95)'
    }
}
```

`AppStlyes` Is not defined. You have no variable declaration.

Instead it should look like this.

```
 const AppStyles = {
    colour: {
        custom: 'rgb(86,200,95)'
    }
};

export default AppStyles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error:

AppStyles sets a property `colour`:

```
export default {
    colour: {
        custom: 'rgb(86,200,95)'
    }
}
```

And you are looking for a property named `color`:

```
AppStyles.color.custom
```

**EDIT:**

You also need to directly export the object. The way you are attempting to export is causing the undefined issue.

Comment: changed it but it still didn't work. Anyways it doesn't even seem to recognize AppStyles

Comment: @james Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite `appstyle.js`:

```
const AppStyles = ...;
export default AppStyles;
```